# Action of the (special) orthogonal group on differential forms

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, invariant-theory

**I was told that the following facts are true. I am looking for a reference to them.**

1) The action of $O(n,\mathbb{C})$ on $\wedge^l\mathbb{C}^n$ is irreducible for any $l$.

2) The action of $SO(n,\mathbb{C})$ on $\wedge^l\mathbb{C}^n$ is irreducible for any $l$, except the case $n=2d$ is even and $l=d$. In the latter case $\wedge^d\mathbb{C}^{2d}$ is direct sum of two irreducible $SO(2d,\mathbb{C})$-representations with highest weights 
$(1,\dots,1,1)$ and $(1,\dots,1,-1)$ respectively (highest weights of $SO(2d,\mathbb{C})$ are identified here with $d$-tuples of numbers).

Comment: Part (2) is a standard result in representation theory.  Look, for example, in Fulton and Harris, *Representation Theory*.  For Part (1), just observe that the irreducible decomposition in Part (2) of $\Lambda^d\mathbb{C}^{2d}$ under $\mathrm{SO}(2d,\mathbb{C})$ is not preserved by $\mathrm{O}(2d,\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: @RobertBryant: Thanks a lot. Indeed Part(2) is contained in the Fulton-Harris book in Theorems 19.2 and 19.14; the highest weights of components of $\wedge^d\mathbb{C}^{2d}$ are written down in Remark (ii) on p. 289. Part (1) follows from Part (2) and Exercise 19.3 on p. 290 (but probably there is a misprint there).